# Is possible to use F# pattern matching as a solver/library for another language or DSL?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, interpreter, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm building a toy language, I want to have pattern matching. I could build the whole thing itself (and don't know how) but because I will do it in F# I wonder if I can defer the whole thing to it.

So, I have a interpreter and my custom syntax. If I give a AST, is possible to use F# use it to solve the pattern matching?

Another way to look at this, is possible to use F# pattern matching from C# and other .NET languages?

For example, if the program is (in invented syntax almost like F#):

```
case x with 
    ( 1 , 2 , Three):
        print("Found 1, 2, or 3!")
    else var1:
        print("%d" % var1)
```

Is possible to do

```
matched, error = F#MagicHere.Match(EvaluateMyAST)
```

Comment: Are you looking for fslex? https://fsprojects.github.io/FsLexYacc/

Comment: No, I'm looking for a way to use F# functionality as a library, so I can implement pattern matching for my language without re-invent what F# already do (because, the language I do is made on top of F#).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand your question correctly, but I suspect you could use [F# Compiler Service](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/) to do what you need. Basically, the compiler service lets you call some of the tasks that the compiler performs (and it is a normal .NET library).

The first step would be to turn your AST into valid F# code - I guess you could find a systematic way of doing this (but it requires some thinking).  Then you can use F.C.S to:

- Type-check the expression, which gives you warnings for overlapping cases and missing cases (e.g. when you have an incomplete pattern match).
- It gives you the AST of the pattern matching and I believe you can even get a decision tree that you can interpret to evaluate the pattern matching.
- Alternatively, you could use F.C.S to compile the code and run it (provided that you can translate your DSL to F# code)

Comment: Look like I need to ship the fsi.exe, and call it from the command line. But if the interpreter is made on F# is kind of inelegant...

Comment: No, F# Compiler Service does not need `fsi.exe`. It is just a single DLL (although a big one) that you can get via NuGet. When using interactive evaluation session, you need to give it a valid executable path, but it does not have to exist (so that the service knows what is its root directory).